# Как, пользуясь переменной, создать таблицу с именем этой переменной. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @_name varchar(50) = 'Great'
CREATE table @_name
        (
            id int identity(1,1) primary key,
            userName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            dateReview date NOT NULL,
            evaluation int NOT NULL CHECK(evaluation > 0 AND evaluation <= 5),
            description varchar(500)
        )
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вам нужно действительно именно это? Необходимость в динамических DDL-запросах, как правило, говорит о неправильном проектировании базы. Случаи, когда они действительно нужны — это очень специфические ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @_name varchar(50) = 'Great' 
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) =
    'CREATE table '+@_name+' ( id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    userName varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    dateReview date NOT NULL, 
    evaluation int NOT NULL CHECK(evaluation > 0 AND evaluation <= 5), 
    description varchar(500) 
    )'
exec(@sql)
```